# Perfect scrollbar not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrollbar, perfect-scrollbar

what am i missing in the following code?
Why is [Perfect scrollbar](http://noraesae.github.io/perfect-scrollbar/) horribly crashing?

It seems it's messing up myDiv scrollbar with browser main scrollbar... any help is appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="perfect-scrollbar.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        #myDiv {
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            overflow: auto;
            background-color: #eeeeee;
            margin: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="myDiv">
    <p>Test perfect scrollbar</p><p>Test perfect scrollbar</p><p>Test perfect scrollbar</p><p>Test perfect scrollbar</p><p>Test perfect scrollbar</p><p>Test perfect scrollbar</p><p>Test perfect scrollbar</p><p>Test perfect scrollbar</p><p>Test perfect scrollbar</p><p>Test perfect scrollbar</p><p>Test perfect scrollbar</p><p>Test perfect scrollbar</p><p>Test perfect scrollbar</p><p>Test perfect scrollbar</p><p>Test perfect scrollbar</p><p>Test perfect scrollbar</p><p>Test perfect scrollbar</p><p>Test perfect scrollbar</p><p>Test perfect scrollbar</p><p>Test perfect scrollbar</p><p>Test perfect scrollbar</p><p>Test perfect scrollbar</p><p>Test perfect scrollbar</p><p>Test perfect scrollbar</p><p>Test perfect scrollbar</p><p>Test perfect scrollbar</p><p>Test perfect scrollbar</p><p>Test perfect scrollbar</p><p>Test perfect scrollbar</p><p>Test perfect scrollbar</p><p>Test perfect scrollbar</p><p>Test perfect scrollbar</p><p>Test perfect scrollbar</p><p>Test perfect scrollbar</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="perfect-scrollbar.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myDiv').perfectScrollbar();
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you [checked your console](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/hello-world/714/using-console-log) for errors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `position:relative` to `#myDiv`

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/gbfLazpx/243/

**CSS:**

```
#myDiv {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

Check the first point here: https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar#requirements

> the container must have a 'position' css style.

Comment: It was him! Thank you, I missed that part.